# Python Selenium add a cookie from Chrome Browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, python-requests

I have some cookie that I see from my Chrome -> Applications -> Cookies. It looks like this:

[image]

Now I convert this cookie to json so I can add it in the Selenium driver. My code looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import json

cookie = {"__Secure-1PSIDCC": "...", "__Secure-3PAPISID": "...", ...} # All the cookie values from the picture
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

But I get an error:

```
/Users/petar.ulev/Documents/lunarcrush/venv/bin/python /Users/petar.ulev/Documents/lunarcrush/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/petar.ulev/Documents/lunarcrush/main.py", line 25, in <module>
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
  File "/Users/petar.ulev/Documents/lunarcrush/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1136, in add_cookie
    self.execute(Command.ADD_COOKIE, {'cookie': cookie_dict})
  File "/Users/petar.ulev/Documents/lunarcrush/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 430, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/petar.ulev/Documents/lunarcrush/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: missing 'name'
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.53)
```

I have seen some other posts that have "name" and "value" in the cookie as keys, but I don't quite understand how to include them in my case. Any ideas how can I add the shown cookie to my selenium browser?

Comment: NOTE: I have tried generating the cookie from the selenium browser itself and then saving it with pickle, but unfortunately I can't pass a verification process of lunarcrush website through selenium (apparently they are detecting it...)

Comment: Try adding the `"Name":"name"` and `"Value":"value"` parts to your cookie dictionary.